# Floating average with reading of ADC values

Tags: c, average, adc, ansi-c

I want to do moving average or something similar to that, because I am getting noisy values from ADC, this is my first try, just to compute moving average, but values goes to 0 everytime, can you help me?

This is part of code, which makes this magic:

```
unsigned char buffer[5];
    int samples = 0;
    USART_Init0(MYUBRR);
    uint16_t adc_result0, adc_result1;
    float ADCaverage = 0;

    while(1)
    {

        adc_result0 = adc_read(0);      // read adc value at PA0
        samples++;
        //adc_result1 = adc_read(1);      // read adc value at PA1

        ADCaverage = (ADCaverage + adc_result0)/samples;

        sprintf(buffer, "%d\n", (int)ADCaverage); 
        char * p = buffer;
        while (*p) { USART_Transmit0(*p++); }
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

This result I am sending via usart to display value.

Comment: Your equation is not correct, try with `ADCaverage +=  (adc_result0-ADCaverage)/samples;`

Comment: ty mate, it works

Comment: If noise is a concern, you might also want to use integers and not float.

Comment: Put my proposal, please mark it as correct.

Comment: Please note that your (incorrect) code and eyllanesc's corrected version is   for a _cumulative_ moving average over all previous data points, but you probably want a _simple_ moving average over the previous _N_ data points for noise filtering purposes.

Comment: yes, i would like to edit it for average of last 100 data points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation is not correct.

Let `s_n = (sum_{i=0}^{n} x[i])/n` then:

```
s_(n-1) = sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x[i])/(n-1)

sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x[i] = (n-1)*s_(n-1)
sum_{i=0}^{n} x[i] = n*s_n


sum_{i=0}^{n} x[i] = sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x[i] + x[n]

n*s_n = (n-1)*s_(n-1) + x[n] =  n*s_(n-1) + (x[n]-s_(n-1))
s_n = s_(n-1) + (x[n]-s_(n-1))/n
```

You must use

```
ADCaverage += (adc_result0-ADCaverage)/samples;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an exponential moving average which only needs 1 memory unit.
`y[0] = (x[0] + y[-1] * (a-1) )/a`
Where **a** is the filter factor.

If **a** is multiples of 2 you can use shifts and optimize for speed significantly:
`y[0] = ( x[0] + ( ( y[-1] << a ) - y[-1] ) ) >> a`

This works especially well with left aligned ADC's. Just keep an eye on the word size of the shift result.